# Why have my Xcode 6.1.1 simulator options all disappeared?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently tried to run a simulation of a new iOS 7 app on Xcode 6.1.1 using my MacBook Pro during a visit to Indonesia. The app was based on AddMusic and made iOS 7 compatible. When I tried to run the simulator abroad iOS simulation targets available while testing in Australia had simply disappeared from the pulldown menu in Xcode. Moreover since I came home these simulators only reappeared when I removed, downloaded and reinstalled Xcode.

Until I reinstalled Xcode the only option Xcode offered was to run the app on an iOS device but I wasn't prepared to do this in front of clients without first being able to test a revision on a simulator.

Thankfully on this occasion I was able to demonstrate earlier versions I had installed on an iPhone 4 and iPhone 5 C before I left home. But it would be really good to know what I might be able to do to avoid this situation during my next visit abroad.

I suspect the issue may have been brought on by differences between my Internet connections at home and abroad.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem that might be related ?

Comment: So did you try to create new simulators under Window > Devices? Did you try to download a new iOS 7 simulator? What did you do? Anything?

Comment: Fascinating. Did you create iOS 8 simulators and they still don't show up as destinations? Weird. I don't think this has anything to do with networks though.

Comment: I was only able to get the drop down menu to show any simulators by changing my deployment target from iOS 8.1 to iOS 7.0. As soon as I did that I could see a bunch of simulators, the latest being iPhone 5s. I guess that's the best I can hope for.

Comment: When I reloaded the latest version of Xcode I was able to use iOS8.1 and iOS 7, as well as simulate on Phone 6 and test on an actual iPhone 5 C. I've had no further problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Top to your Right Click on 
**Window > Devices**

You will see that no devices will be showing Do the following
Bottom Left 
Click on the + 
And then start adding your devices.

Comment: I got my simulators disappeared when i messed up with Simulators folder, This step helped me get those back!!

Answer (score 1):

Just closing the projects from the File Menu, quitting Xcode and restarting Xcode worked for me
the version is the latest Xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

Some things which might help you

1. Check deployment target in your project settings. Switching to lower versions of OS might help you get back all simulators.
   [image]
2. Check your xcode version used in the command line tools. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command line tools
3. Quit Xcode and restart your system.

Hope these things help !!